# Is the Matrix ring over the a radical ideal a radical ideal of the matrix ring?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

That is, if $I$ is an ideal filled with quasi-regular elements contained in ring $R$, are elements of the matrix ideal $M_n(I)$ also quasi-regular?

It can be explicitly shown in the low dimensional cases, but can anyway attest or prove the general result? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes: as you probably we'll know, the ideals of $R$ and those of $M_n(R)$ are in correspondence via the map $I\to M_n(I)$. Moreover this map preserves containment and intersections.

If U is a right primitive ideal, say the annihilator of the simple R module S, then it's easy to show that $\oplus_{i=1}^n S$ Is a simple right $M_n(R)$ module with annihilator $M_n(U)$. Taking the intersection of all right primitive ideals, you get that the Jacobson radical J of R maps to the Jacobson radical of $M_n(R)$.

Thus an ideal contained in J will map to a ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of $M_n(R)$.

By the way, it is not very standard to call such an ideal "radical." Usually it means an ideal that is an intersection of prime ideals. Your usage is logical, but a little unusual :)